# Question about Tikz Template

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, templates, exam

I'm really stuck i want to create something like this image in bellow but i didn't know how to start because i'm beginner in tikz

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into `tcolorbox`? Its not as flexible as tikz, but I think it is a lot more friendly for a beginner and might get you close enough. Depending on how much effort you are willing to put in and how choosy you are about the result.
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Comment: That is similar to the effect of page 180 of the latest version of [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

Comment: If you're asking for the *Exercice 1* header, definitely `tcolorbox`. If you're also asking for the left pattern, you should consider making a `pic` and using it as a background for all your pages. But these are two different questions that you may ask into two different posts.